# how to get json object from json array

Tags: json

How to get JSONObject from JSONArray?

I had JSONArray like this:

```
[
  {
    "id0": 0,
    "name0": "Test hd",
    "customerType0": "Company",
    "businessType0": "Buyer",
    "city0": "Thirunelveli"
  },
  {
    "id1": 1,
    "name1": "Abcd abcdefghij",
    "customerType1": "Company",
    "businessType1": "Buyer",
    "city1": "Varanasi"
  },
  {
    "id2": 2,
    "name2": "test ",
    "customerType2": "Company",
    "businessType2": "Buyer",
    "city2": "Erode"
  },
  {
    "id3": 3,
    "name3": "New customer",
    "customerType3": "Company",
    "businessType3": "Buyer",
    "city3": "Coimbatore"
  }
]
```

And i want to get each object seperately and made that data to be displayed in the format aS Html table.

I tried:

```
function table_ajax()
{
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "Customergrouptable_servlet",
        data: "searchname="+$('.cnames').val(),
        success: function(data)
        {
            tableobj = JSON.parse(data)
            cusobj=tableobj.customerdetail;

            $(cusobj).each(function(index, cusobj){

                alert("index"+index);// Here i can get the index for that object. I dont know how to get the object values has stored.

            });
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Please indent your code so it's easy to read. It only takes a minute and it really helps. To make formatting JSON easier, try this: `JSON.stringify(obj, null, '  ')`

Answer (score 0):

every time that your function fired 
you have your array child on cusobj.

now on this sample json you have 4 child

```
 [{
     "id0": 0,
     "name0": "Test hd",
     "customerType0": "Company",
     "businessType0": "Buyer",
     "city0": "Thirunelveli"
 }, {
     "id1": 1,
     "name1": "Abcd abcdefghij",
     "customerType1": "Company",
     "businessType1": "Buyer",
     "city1": "Varanasi"
 }, {
     "id2": 2,
     "name2": "test ",
     "customerType2": "Company",
     "businessType2": "Buyer",
     "city2": "Erode"
 }, {
     "id3": 3,
     "name3": "New customer",
     "customerType3": "Company",
     "businessType3": "Buyer",
     "city3": "Coimbatore"
 }]
```

and every time you have one of them on cusobj
you can easyli access them using

cusobj.name3 , cusobj.id3

EDIT : 
also you are on wrong way 
you don't need to add number after keys

just use as
cusobj.name , cusobj.id